# Error in JS duplicate array entry method

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add user inputs into an array and throw an error alert if the user enters a duplicate value. The method below works fine for duplicates, but it also throws errors for non duplicate values. I am unable to understand why. Its probably something very simple, but I'm not seeing it.

```
addDIN(val) {
    var arr = this.din_require_list;
    if (arr.length == 0) {
      arr.push(val)
    }
    else if (arr.length > 0) {
      for (var i= 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (val != arr[i]) {
          arr.push(val);
        } 
        else if(val == arr[i]){
          alert("duplicate entry");    
         arr.splice(i+1,1);
        }
      };
    };

  }
```

[image: Img1], 
[image: Img2]

Comment: what's `din_require_list`?

Comment: Its an array that is initialised.

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: `function( val ){ if( this.din_require_list.includes( val ) { throw Error('...'); } else { this.din_require_list.push( val ); } }`

Comment: Is there a reason you didn't crop those images?

Comment: @Amy Sorry I don't understand what you mean. The above images show the error thrown even if the input value if different. Had to crop out the rest because confidential info.

Comment: @kaveripatnam.vivek crop out all of the useless blank space.  https://i.imgur.com/iTM14o8.png  90% of your screenshots are empty space.  Crop it out.

Answer (score 0):

make it simpler

```
function insertUnique(val){
  var arr = [];
  if(!arr.includes(val)){
    arr.push(val)
  }else{
    alert("Duplicate entry");
  }
}
```

Array.include checks whether the value exists or not in given array.

refer this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes

Answer (score 0):

You are pushing into the array but not exiting the loop, so the loop keeps on running and matches the value and throws the error,

What you should be doing is run the for loop separately  and keep a flag if it has a duplicate or not, and if no dupes are found add the element to the array

like

```
  for (var i= 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
         if(arr[i]== val){
           dupeFound==1;
           console.log("duplicate")
           break;
          }
  }
  if(dupeFound!=1) array.push(val)
```

Answer (score 0):

at risk of being simplistic

why not?

```
var arr = [1,2,'c','dude what'];
var lookfor = 'dude';

    if(arr.indexOf(lookfor) != -1){
        console.log('dude string already exists on the array')
    }
```

Therefore

```
var arr = [1,2,'c','dude what'];

var add = 1;
if((arr.indexOf(add) == -1)?arr.push(add): false){
  console.log('added ',add);
}else{
  console.log(add,'already in array');
}

console.log(arr);
```